# How do I download a file from chatter in visualforce page?

Tags: javascript, rest-api, chatter, ajax, xml

I am new to Salesforce. I have a large xml file in Chatter/Files that I need to download and process on the client. How can I get the file? I am able to get static resources via ajax, but this file is larger than the 5mb limit. In the chatter UI, the download file link url is
 https://c.cs17.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068g0000000TQFu?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER

I see an entry in the rest api docs that seems like a better way to go.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_files_content.htm

Can I use REST to retrieve to get the file from the client. I am using jQuery and  this is a visualforce page.

Comment: What do you mean by process on the client? Also, FYI, your first link is inaccessible to anyone not logged in to your org.

Comment: yes Brian I realize that, I just wanted to show the URL. The rest approach seems a good way to go. By process, I mean parse the xml document and do some further processing with the data it contains. Thanks.

Comment: Hi did you ever solve this. I am having the same problem. Please write a answer if you did :)